# Why does my controller have access to one model, but not another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, model, controller

I have a controller named User. In two of its actions, I would like to access a model named Preference. I receive an "uninitialized constant UserController::Preferences" error when trying to tap either action.

I am able to access other models such as Prospect without error. Both Prospect and Preference are related have a belongs_to relationship with User.

I've tried accessing the model as ::Preferences, but I receive this very similar error: "uninitialized constant Preferences". I've also tried manually requiring the model, to no avail.

Has anyone else run into this problem and come up with a solution?

Comment: Like you said, the model is named `Preference`.

Comment: Please show the code for models User, Prospect and Preference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are calling it "Preferences". But that is almost certainly not the name of your model.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show #or whatever
    @user = User.find(67)
    @preferences = user.preferences
    # OR
    @preferences = Preference.where(:user_id => @user.id).first
  end
end
```

Note that when we call Preference, it is singular.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. It's funny how 2 programmers can sit around a screen for 10 minutes and not pick up on this. Sometimes all it takes is a look in from the outside.

Comment: @Fingerfactor you're welcome -- and I agree, one of the best things about SO is the fresh perspective another dev can bring.